# How can I change a database for accounts by DDP on meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have an meteor app "A" using accounts-base, accounts-ui, accounts-twitter, and accounts-weibo.

I decided to make another meteor app "B", that is basically same as the above but especially for mobile devices.

Are there any ways to change a database that accounts packages use on B, to A's?

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, though not absolutely sure. Something like this may work:

```
var connection = DDP.connect("http://other_server");

Meteor.users = new Meteor.Collection("users", { connection: connection });
```

If you get a 'collection is already defined error' you may have to fork accounts-base and use this in place of what is used for Meteor.users & it should be fine.

What it does is it pretends to be a DDP client for the other server, allowing your users from app B use the `users` collection from app `A`, yet have a separate database for itself.

THe other option is to share the same `MONGO_URL` as the other app, and you wouldn't have to worry about modifying the accounts-base package (if you have to)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I found a simpler way. Writing the following line in server code.
__meteor_runtime_config__.ACCOUNTS_CONNECTION_URL = '<primary URL>';
But both yours and mine do not solve oauth callback.